# How to print the first line which include special word

Tags: shell, awk, grep, cat, head

Print the first 123 below XXX

```
AAA
BCB
DDD
123
123
XXX
CCC
123
123
MSM
123
```

Comment: AAA is the first line BCB is second line...

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/486604/edit) Include what you have tried so far and what is not working. Thank you!

Comment: What is different about the *first* `123` after `XXX`?  Would a simple `echo 123` do what you need?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Probably, _if you were sure that such a line occurred in the input, in the way specified_.

Comment: The difference is the first one "under XXX" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1, /XXX/ {next}; /123/ {print; exit}' < input.txt
```

would skip all the lines up to the first one that contains `XXX` and then print the first line that contains `123` in the remaining lines.

For arbitrary strings stored in variables:

```
START='XXX' NEEDLE='fancy string with " and *' awk '
  NR == 1, index($0, ENVIRON["START"]) {next}
  index($0, ENVIRON["NEEDLE"]) {print; exit}' < input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working!! How can I change this if the 123 is "prefer A B" included a space and quotation mark?

Comment: @youngchaw, just change `/123/` to `/"prefer A B"/`.  See also edit in case your string may  contain slashes or regexp operators

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n '/XXX/,$ { /123/ { p; q; }; }' <file
123
```

This applies the `p` command to print the current line, followed by the `q` command to quit, to a line that matches `123`.  The test for `123` is done on all lines between the first that matches `XXX` and the end of the input (inclusively).

To exclude the `XXX` lines (the `123` must not occur on the same line as a `XXX` line):

```
$ sed -n '/XXX/,$ { /XXX/d; /123/ { p; q; }; }' <file
123
```

Comment: Tighter: `<infile sed '1,/XXX/d ; /123/!d ; q'`

Comment: That starts checking for 123 *with* the first matching XXX, not the first line after that.

Comment: @Isaac, that wouldn't work properly if the first occurrence of `XXX` was on the first line. Better with `/XXX/,$!d`. But that  could also print the XXX line if it  contained both XXX and 123

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (1) *That starts checking for 123 with the first matching XXX, not the first line after that.* **Yes** exactly as this answer also did. (2) First line? Use `sed '0,/XXX/d…` with GNU sed (3) It doesn't seem like the input values will have XXX and 123 on the same line. But, if that is a requirement, and the use of old sed is also required, use: `sed '/XXX/,$!d;/XXX/d;/123/!d;q'`.

Comment: This answer also works. Thanks a lot for your answers!